# Related content by Association in Ruby (on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Let's say I got questions that have multiple tags on them. I want to be able to find related questions by tags (similar to e.g. iTunes Genius) or find related tags for a tag based on the questions that share them.

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do that. Especially when it comes to related tags.

I hope somebody can give me a hint! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PinnyM I've searched the web for a gem and I tried to chain some where()clauses but since it can be a random amount of matching tags for questions I don't know how to do that. Sorry that I have no code to share since I didn't found out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accomplishing this efficiently requires a strong understanding of SQL.  You can use ActiveRecord to help you build the queries, but the strategy actually lies in the SQL  query that will be generated.

Assuming you have Tag and Question models with a `QuestionTag` join model for a `has-many-through` relationship:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :question_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_tags
  has_many :questions, :through => :question_tags
end

class QuestionTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

You can do this to find questions matching a particular tag:

```
tag = Tag.find_by(name: 'foo')
related_questions = tag.questions
```

And you can also find questions that match all of a set of tags:

```
tag_names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
subquery = QuestionTag.joins(:tag).
             select('question_tags.question_id').
             where(tags: {name: tag_names}).
             group('question_tags.question_id').
             having("COUNT(*) = #{tag_names.size}").to_sql
related_questions = Question.where("id IN (#{subquery})")
```

You can find tags related to a specific tag like this:

```
tag = Tag.find_by(name: 'foo')
subquery = tag.question_tags.select('question_tags.question_id').to_sql
related_tags = Tag.joins(:question_tags).
                 where("question_tags.question_id IN #{subquery}").
                 where.not(id: tag.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer! I'll try it after work.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a many-to-many relationship meaning that questions can have many tags and tags many questions. To do this you must create a third table the consists of tag_ids and question_ids to do this you will need to read up on active record associations.   Specifically the has-many-through association. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association
I am currently taking a web development class and we went over this yesterday with students and classes here are our notes. Which walks through creating the models and using them I suspect it would be really helpful for you. https://github.com/wdi-sf-jan-2014/notes/blob/master/active_record_associations/migrations_and_associations.md

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. But what if I'm looking for all questions that have similar tags. Like my current question has tag a, tag b and tag c. Now I want to have all questions with those tags

Comment: so assuming you have a instance of a tag you can do tag.questions.all

Comment: Yeah. But if I have an instance of a question and want to get some related questions, like 'question.related_questions'. This method should find the tags for my question. Then it should find all the questions that have those tags in common.

Comment: You could implement that method yourself in the questions model you could get the tags using `tags = self.tags.all Question.find_each{|q| q.tags = tags}` which I believe would give you all the questions that had the exact same tags.

Comment: Should be == not = in `Question.find_each{|q| q.tags == tags}`